# how can reset qtreemodel ? how remove rows function should look like?

Tags: c++, qt

All,

I made my own TreeModel, inherits from QAbstractItemModel.
the user has the option to reload new data, when he clicks there the model should be changed, but with the same data, I mean the view of the data should be changed, so I run over the current model, save the data, create new model with new data view and load it.

my problem is that i use the proxy model to enable filtering and coloring in the tree, when i do what I explained above i lose the coloring option, it does not color as expected (as was before the user clicked on the option).

is it right just to create new model, without cleaning the previous model ?? ( and surly update the proxy model too).
if yes, why do i lose the right behavior of the coloring ?

how can i reset my previous model ? how the remove rows function should look like ??

can anyone please write me a code of remove rows function for a tree model ?

thanks alot :))

Answer (score 0):

doing a full reset is easy:

```
void clear(){
    beginResetModel();
    //remove from internal list
    endResetModel();
}
```

you can also set the new model in between the `*ResetModel()` calls

Comment: i did that, but the tool is crashing after calling endResetModel(), or after calling reset()...